# How to do laravel currency conversion

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying do currency conversion in laravel 5.

I don't know how to do it.As far I had search so many things to do multiple currency conversion.

But I don't know how and where to start it.

Is there any composer update or install need!!..To do this!!

please someone guide me

Answer (score 3):

Remember: Currency conversion is just math, the difficult part is ensuring those pesky exchange rates are up to date! (Sorta). You will be able to use something like:

https://github.com/florianv/laravel-swap - This will facilitate all of your needs.

The documentation there is great, but on a low level using the facade you can do something like:

```
 $rate = Swap::quote('EUR/USD');
```

After you have registered the facade & added the providers to your app.php

Comment: Does the `florianv/laravel-swap` convert only upto two currencies!!...

Comment: Yes probably however - You will be able to method chain & use variables to assign swapped amounts and then reapply the swap. For example: $rate = Swap::quote('EUR/USD');  $rateGBP = Swap::quote('USD/GBP'); and you will convert to USD from EUR and then from USD to GBP. The value of rateGBP will then be GBP from EUR.

Answer (score 1):

following link can help you to convert currency. You will have to add following line inside `require` array of your `composer.json`

```
"cartalyst/converter": "2.0.*"
```

Then add the following lines after the `require` array on your `composer.json` file:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.cartalyst.com"
    }
]
```

And after doing this things just do composer update inside your project folder. and after it follow the instruction given on below documentation page.
https://cartalyst.com/manual/converter/2.0

Hope it will help you.

Comment: "cartalyst/converter" dies not work with newer than Laravel 5.3  because on an error. `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share()` It seems like they abandoned their package